# jQuery Mobile Multiple Dialog Boxes in One Dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have searched and have not found example of doing this. I want to be able to have a dialog box open for jQM and have it where there is a step by step process that takes place inside of one dialog box. I am figuring this would require multiple dialog boxes loading into one dialog box and don't know if this is possible. We are using Backbone with jQM and want to be able to load the underscore templates in the dialog box for each step of the way. I am figuring it would be 4-5 steps in the dialog box.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: you can do it using .`html()` and `.trigger('pagecreate')`. will work on such an example if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, using `.show()` and `.hide()`. The trick here is to create several divs, and then show/hide them.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xXQQh/)

Markup

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
  <h1>Dialog</h1>
 </div>

<!-- First Page -->
 <div data-role="content" id="page1">
  <h3>Page 1</h3>
  <p>Text for #page1</p>
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="prev">Previous</a>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="next">Next</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<!-- Second Page -->

<div data-role="content" id="page2">
  <h3>Page 2</h3>
  <p>Text for #page2</p>
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="prev">Previous</a>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="next">Next</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<!-- Third Page -->
<div data-role="content" id="page3">
  <h3>Page 3</h3>
  <p>Text for #page3</p>
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="prev">Previous</a>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="next">Next</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Code

```
// hide previous button, #page2 and #page3 once opened
$('#dialog').find('#page1 a.prev').hide();
$('#page2, #page3').hide();

// #page1 to #page2
$('#page1 a.next').on('click', function () {
 $('#page1').hide();
 $('#page2').show();
});

// #page2 to #page3
$('#page2 a.next').on('click', function () {
 $('#page1, #page2').hide();
 $('#page3').show();
 $('#dialog').find('#page3 a.next').hide();
});

// #page2 to #page1
$('#page2 a.prev').on('click', function () {
 $('#page2').hide();
 $('#page1').show();
});

// #page3 to #page2
$('#page3 a.prev').on('click', function () {
 $('#page2, #page3').hide();
 $('#page2').show();
});
```