# Jquery Mobile - On a dialog how to change the "delete" icon in the header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, markup, jquery-mobile-button

I have the following structure:

```
<div data-rola="dialog" id="languages" data-close-btn="right" 
data-direction="reverse">
    <header data-role="header">
        <a href="#" id="closeMenu" data-role="button" data-icon="home" 
        data-iconpos="notext" data-corners="true" data-iconshadow="false">
            Close
        </a>
        <h2>LANGUAGES</h2>
     </header>
    <section data-role="content">
        <ul class="jqm-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right" 
                data-shadow="false" data-wrapperels="div">
                    Text
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

I want to change the dialog "delete" icon for the "arrow-l" icon, because this dialog menu is the second one menu that will appear after showing the general one. And clicking on that icon is not going to close the dialog, it is going to move back to the previous menu.

Can anyone explain me how can I change the icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this line:

```
$('#closeMenu').buttonMarkup({ icon: "arrow-l" });
```

Official documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/ search for an option "icon".

**EDIT :**

Here's a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nBGMQ/

In it, original icons for a back button was **home**. This code:

```
$('#previous').buttonMarkup({ icon: "arrow-l" });
```

changed it to **arrow-l**.

Example was taken from **[Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar)** and its answer: **[jQuery Mobile Multiple Dialog Boxes in One Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15904607/1848600)**

Comment: It's not the #closeMenu the icon I want to change, this I can change it with 
    data-icon"arrow-l"
I want to change the icon on the
    div data-role="header"
I have tried 
    $('#closeMenu').buttonMarkup({ icon: "arrow-l" });
and it is not working

Comment: Can you update your question with your full dialog HTML? This way I can see what needs to be changed and can create a jsFiddle example for you.

Comment: It's not working on my site, I have even tried with
    $('#languages').buttonMarkup({ "option", "icon", "home" });
What I want to do Gajotres is to change the icon with the "X" the one that closes the dialog.

Comment: I showed ou how to change icon, even gave you an example. Cant help you more then that. You can mail me your project end I will take a look.

Comment: Yes, you showed how to change an icon, but I was looking on how to change the default "delete" icon on the popup.
I found a solution on that [fiddle](http://alturl.com/2eo7t)